# Where can I find Vista/Win7 Virtual Display Drivers?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, drivers, multiple-monitors, display

I'm looking for a virtual display driver similar to the one included in [ZoneOS ZoneScreen](http://www.zoneos.com/zonescreen.htm) that does not have the limitations of WDDM so that it can be used in Windows 7 of Windows Vista.

All I need is something to emulate a display adapter and a monitor so it shows up in the display properties. I then intend to use a VNC server with the display device set to that virtual display, and I can then use any VNC client as an additional monitor.

ZoneScreen works great in Windows XP for this exact purpose. It won't work in Vista/Win7 for the following reason:

> **Windows Vista and Windows 7 Limitations**
>
> These operating systems have two important limitations affecting
> ZoneScreen display driver. First, due
> to Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM)
> architecture, ZoneScreen virtual
> display driver can't run unless legacy
> XP drivers are installed on main video
> adapter. Also, for Windows
> Vista x64 and Windows 7 x64 digital
> signature enforcement for kernel
> drivers is also applied (ZoneScreen
> driver do have authenticode signature
> but appropriate digital certificate
> costs a lot). So, virtual display
> driver is not loaded unless this
> enforcement is disabled.

Can anyone tell me if such a thing exists?

Comment: Did you ever find what you were looking for? I would be interested too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just found this: http://virtualmonitor.github.io/  Looks like a work-in-progress and only supports windows 2000 - windows 7, but he's looking for help with windows 7 - 8.

Comment: Looks awesome! Starred the project, this is exactly what I've been looking for.. but seems like it has some distance to travel still. 4 years later... better late than never, i guess?

Comment: Unfortunately current 0.2.1 Beta release outputs "Unsupported Windows system" while I'm trying to install it on Windows 8.1

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the Quartics Virtual Display Driver 10.0.0.5 helps you (google or look at your favourite download-page for it).
If this is not what you need, following page could be interesting for you:
http://forum.ultravnc.info/viewtopic.php?t=6408

Comment: This display driver you mentioned was last updated in April of 2005. It is certainly not compatible with Windows 7 or Windows Vista. In addition, your link shows only a forum thread where people are asking the same questions that I am and providing answers I already mentioned here (ZoneOS).